# How can I change character code from Shift-JIS to UTF-8 when I copy data from DB2 to Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, db2, pentaho, spoon

I'm trying to migrate data from DB2 to Postgres using pentaho ETL now.
character code on DB2 is Shift-JIS (Japanese specific character code) and Postgres is UTF-8.

I could migrate data from DB2 to Postgres successfully, but Japanese character has not been transformed properly (it has been changed to strange characters..)

How can I change character code from Shift-Jis to UTF-8 when I transfer data?

Comment: As far as I investigated, Jdbc can use only UTF-8, thus, I might have to convert character code after Pentaho get data from DB2(source DB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was bit though problem for me, but I could solve it finally.

first, you need to choose "Modified Java Script value" from job list and write the script as below.
(I'm assuming that the value in the table is column1 and new value is value1)

[image: steps]

here is the example of the source code. (You can specify multiple values if you need)

> var **value1** = new Packages.java.lang.String(new
>   Packages.java.lang.String(**column1**).getBytes("ISO8859_1"),"Shift-JIS").replaceAll("　","");
>   //you don't need to use `replaceAll()` if you don't need to trim the string.

---

Finally, click "Get variables" and the value will be shown in the table below.

[image]

then, you can choose the "value1" in the next job and it has been converted to correct encode. (which you specified)